# jQuery Mobile Issues - First time user

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

So I am using jQuery mobile for the first time.

I have added it in and I have the swiperight function working to go back to the previous page.

However as I have been navigating around I have notice a couple of things which have come at a cost of adding jQuery mobile. I managed to stop the changing of elements such as inputs etc by using `$( "input, textarea, select", e.target ).attr( "data-role", "none" );`.

1). The loading message displays at the bottom of the screen. I removed this by using `$.mobile.loadingMessage = false;` however it is still causing a scroll bar when it is not needed which is causing a white line below my footer.

2). On one of my pages I have the following code which now no longer works:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#arrow_click").click(function(){

        var theclass = $(this).attr("class");

        if(theclass == "icon-chevron-down"){
            $("#table_cont").hide();
        } else if(theclass == "icon-chevron-up"){
            $("#table_cont").show();
        }

    });

});
```

Can anyone shed any light on these two issues?

Thanks

Comment: looks like you have some other javascript error blocking this... check your console for error

Comment: No errors in the console.

Comment: Ok so issue number 2 was due to jQuery mobile appending ui-link as a class to the link so I change the code to this:    if(theclass.indexOf("icon-chevron-down") != -1){ and it now works. Not worked out the white space issue yet.

Answer (score 2):

Jquery adds the below loading div at the end pages as below.

```
<div class="ui-loader ui-corner-all ui-body-a ui-loader-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-loading"></span>

 <h1>loading</h1>

</div>
```

To get rid of it, you have two options, either to .`hide();` it or `.remove();` it by calling the div's class `ui-loader`. Try either solution.

**Hide it.**

`.hide();` adds `display: none;` style to the div, but it doesn't remove it.

```
$(document).on("pageshow", "[data-role='page']", function () {
 $('div.ui-loader').hide();
});
```

**Remove it.**

`.remove();` removes the div and its' contents. So you need to use this wisely, in case you want to show the loading message in other pages.

```
$(document).on("pageshow", "[data-role='page']", function () {
 $('div.ui-loader').remove();
});
```

If you want to keep the loading message in some pages, assign a `class` for the pages with no loading message i.e. `.no-loadmsg` and use the same code above but instead of `[data-role='page']` add `[data-role='page'].no-loadmsg`.

```
$(document).on("pageshow", "[data-role='page'].no-loadmsg", function () {
 $('div.ui-loader').remove();
});
```

This will remove loading div from desired pages with `.no-loadmsg` class only.

I hope the above solves your problem.